# JavaScript innerHTML

Tags: javascript

Why doesn't this work? innerHTML cannot take in something so complicated?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function addTable() {
            var html = "<table><tr><td><label for="name">Name:</label></td><td><input type="text" id="name"></input></td></tr>"; +
                "<tr><td><label for="remarks">Remarks:</label></td><td><input type="text" id="remarks"></input></td></tr></table>";
            document.getElementById("addtable").innerHTML = html;
        }
    </script>


</head>
<body>
    <input type="submit" value="New Table" onClick="addTable()"/>
    <div id="addtable"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Something less complicated like this works:

```
var html = "<table><tr><td>123</td><td>456</td></tr></table>";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to either escape double quotes within the string you're assigning to the `html` variable, or just enclose the string with single quotes. Use a text editor with syntax highlighting and errors like that will jump out at you right away. You also have an extra semicolon in your assignment.

Comment: That's the main reason why I use single quotes to signify strings in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Your quoting is broken. You are using double quotes inside the string:

```
"<tr><td><label for="remarks">Remarks:</label></td><td><input ....
```

the Firefox error console should always be your first stop, errors like that are always logged there.

Answer (score 1):

Your string is delimited using double quotes and also uses them within the string. Switch to using single quotes within the string.

```
var html = "<table><tr><td><label for='name'>Name:</label></td><td><input type='text' id='name'></input></td></tr>"; +
"<tr><td><label for='remarks'>Remarks:</label></td><td><input type='text' id='remarks'></input></td></tr></table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of double quotes use single quotes as shown below:

var html = "<table><tr><td><label for='name'>Name:</label></td><td><input type='text' id='name'></input></td></tr>' + 
                "<tr><td><label for='remarks'>Remarks:</label></td><td><input type='text' id='remarks'></input></td></tr></table>";

Enjoy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to either escape double quotes or use single quotes within the string destined for that innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your string , try this :

var html = "Name:"; +
                "Remarks:";
            document.getElementById("addtable").innerHTML = html;