MudBlazor: GridState FilterDefinitions cannot be sent to API (serialization issue)
We are trying to use the GridState with an API.
Everything works great except when we add a custom filter (GridState.FilterDefinitons.Add).
The razor part:
<MudDataGrid @ref="@datagrid" T="Person" ServerData="ServerDataApiCaller" FixedHeader Dense="true" Striped="true" Bordered="true" ColumnResizeMode="ResizeMode.Column">
    <Columns>
        <PropertyColumn Property="p => p.Name" Title="Name" />
    </Columns>
</MudDataGrid>

The razor.cs part:
...
var filter = new FilterDefinition<Person>()
{
    Column = dataGrid!.RenderedColumns.First(x => x.Title == "Name"),
    Title = "Name",
    Operator = "contains",
    Value = "bob"
};

gridState.FilterDefinitions.Add(filter);

httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync($"/api/v1/people", gridState);   // Raise an error
...

Here below the error shown in the console in the Browser DevTools:
blazor.webassembly.js:1 
 crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Serialization and deserialization of 'System.Action' instances is not supported. Path: $.FilterDefinitions.Column.DataGrid.PagerStateHasChangedEvent.
...

It seems that the FilterDefinitions could not be serialized.
The API is not even called (the API call does not appear in the Browser DevTools/Network), that means the runtime failed at the serialization.
Does anyone have succeeded to use FilterDefinitions (GridState) by calling an API? Or do we misuse the FilterDefinitions?

Can you include another part of your code where the endpoint is calles?
As the error shows, Column is an object with actions. If you don't set it, the serialization should be succesful or at least show another error

@Uerschel I added the razor part. The endpoint is not called before the error. If it was called, I would see it in the Browser DevTools/Network. If I remove the filter, the endpoint will appear in the Browser DevTools/Network and the call would be successful.

You are trying to serialize an expression tree.  There have been several projects over time trying to solve the problem.  I don't think any are still alive which tells you how complex the problem is - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325339 9/serialize-expression-tree.  I use canned expressions - serialize a request object with a query name and a data object.   The server reads the data, plugs it into the query, executes the filter, sorting and returns a result object.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis I agree, there is probably a circular reference in the FilterDefinition object (the error mentions '$.FilterDefinitions.Column.DataGrid.PagerStateHasChangedEvent'). Column references DataGrid which itself contains all the columns. But this is MudBlazor internal code, I tried to override DataGrid (filter.Column.DataGrid = null), but there is no effect in runtime.

Pose an issue on the MudBlazor Github site - https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/issues
